# Why does passing arguments to the command in an env invocation not work?

Tags: node.js, shell, ubuntu, shebang

I have a shell script to run node with some arguments like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --harmony_proxies
...
```

This works fine under OS X but in Ubuntu it errors with:

```
/usr/bin/env: node --harmony_proxies: No such file or directory
```

Node is definitely installed and on the PATH since if I remove the `--harmony_proxies` flag it works fine. Is there some different way of passing arguments when using `env` in Ubuntu?

Comment: Just to be sure, does `/usr/bin/env node --harmony_proxies script-name` work correctly on the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Linux, the entire string following the interpreter name is passed as a single argument to the interpreter, and this string can include white space. [[1]](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/netbsd-users/2008/11/09/msg002388.html) Thus, command line arguments are not split, and `env` command is trying to execute `node --harmony_proxies` file, which obviously could not be found. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and [here](http://mail-index.netbsd.org/netbsd-users/2008/11/09/msg002388.html) for more details.

Here is an alternative solution for you:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec node --harmony_proxies "$@"
```

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If the `node` command is installed in a fixed location, you can use it directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/node --harmony_proxies
```

But if you can't assume that `node` is installed in a particular location, go with one of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the source, [a wrapper alias](https://github.com/smikes/node/blob/minus-x-switch/doc/Minus-X-Switch-Proposal.md#alias) might be the right solution.

Example from my .bashrc:

```
alias how2='/usr/bin/env node --no-deprecation "$(which how2)"'
```